Scrollbar alter tamanho da tabela e do frame no tkinter
Estou com problema para criar as barras de rolagem na minha aplicação no tkinter. Eu quero que a area da tabela ocupe o frame todo, porém quando eu insiro a scrollbar. Na primeira imgaem é antes de eu inserir e a segunda é após:


import customtkinter as ct
from tkinter import ttk
from CTkMenuBar import *
import sqlite3
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd    
   
class App(ct.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("SADJud")
        w = 1024
        h = 760
        ws = self.winfo_screenwidth()
        hs = self.winfo_screenheight()
        x = (ws/2)-(w/2)
        y = (hs/2)-(h/2)
        self.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
        self.menu = self.menus()
        self.tabela = self.areaTbl()

    def menus(self):
        menu = CTkMenuBar(self)
        btnResFavGov = menu.add_cascade("Resgates a Favor do Estado")
        dropdown1 = CustomDropdownMenu(widget=btnResFavGov)
        dropdown1.add_option(option="Por Data", command=self.rfvPorData)
        dropdown1.add_separator()
        dropdown1.add_option(option="Por Conta Judicial")
        dropdown1.add_separator()
        dropdown1.add_option(option="Por Processo Judicial")
        dropdown1.add_separator()
        dropdown1.add_option(option="Por CPF/CNPJ do Reclamante")
        dropdown1.add_separator()
        dropdown1.add_option(option="Por CPF/CNPJ do Reclamado")
        dropdown1.add_separator()
        dropdown1.add_option(option="Por CPF/CNPJ do Reclamante")
        dropdown1.add_separator()
        dropdown1.add_option(option="Por Nome do Reclamante")
        dropdown1.add_separator()
        dropdown1.add_option(option="Por Nome do Reclamado")
        dropdown1.add_separator()
        btnSair = menu.add_cascade("Sair")
        dropdownsair = CustomDropdownMenu(widget=btnSair)
        dropdownsair.add_option(option="Sobre")
        dropdownsair.add_separator()
        dropdownsair.add_option(option="Sair", command=quit)

    def areaTbl(self):
        areatabela = ct.CTkFrame(self, width=1024, height=600)
        areatabela.place(x=0, y=29)
        tbl = ttk.Treeview(areatabela)
        tbl.place(relheight=1, relwidth=1)
        treescrolly = ttk.Scrollbar(areatabela, orient="vertical", command=tbl.yview)
        treescrollx = ttk.Scrollbar(areatabela, orient="horizontal", command=tbl.xview)
        tbl.configure(xscrollcommand=treescrollx.set, yscrollcommand=treescrolly.set)
        treescrollx.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
        treescrolly.pack(side="right", fill = "y")


Após pesquisas consiga achar uma solução, que foi criar um canvas dentro do frame e aí sim criar o scrollbar. No fim o código da função que cria ficou:
    def areaTbl(self):
    areatabela = ct.CTkFrame(self, width=1024, height=600)
    #areatabela.place(x=0, y=29)
    areatabela.pack()
    ysb = ttk.Scrollbar(areatabela, orient="vertical")
    xsb = ttk.Scrollbar(areatabela, orient="horizontal")
    canvasTabela = ct.CTkCanvas(areatabela, width=1024, height=600)
    canvasTabela.configure(scrollregion=canvasTabela.bbox(tk.ALL), xscrollcommand=xsb.set,
                           yscrollcommand=ysb.set)
    xsb.config(command=canvasTabela.xview)
    ysb.config(command=canvasTabela.yview)
    ysb.pack(side='right', fill='y', expand=1)
    xsb.pack(side='bottom', fill='x', expand=1)
    canvasTabela.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=1)
    tbl = ttk.Treeview(canvasTabela)
    tbl.place(relheight=1, relwidth=1)

